# Is a Parse query fetching an Object multiple times when referenced by multiple rows?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-framework

If I do a query in parse where I call "includeKey" to simultaneously fetch referenced objects and the same object is referenced by multiple rows, will it be loaded only once or once per row? If it is fetched once per row there would be a massive overhead which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include is implemented as a separate query which gets all the objects pointed to by the initial query. So the answer is no, this object is not fetched again by each row that points to it, since all the included objects are fetched at once in a separate query.